# Get values from a class into a dictionary

Tags: c#, class, select

I have an object `volresult` containing a list of IDs (`int`), Date (`DateTime`), and prices (`double`).

I want to use those values in another project and to avoid circular references when passing object `volresult` I want to pass Dates and Prices as a `Dictionary<DateTime, Double>`.

I have tried:

```
var try1 = results.values.Select(x => new {x.Date, x.Prices}).ToDictionary(DateTime, Double);
var try2 = results.values.ToDictionary<DateTime, Double>(x => new {x.Date, x.Prices});
var try3 = results.values.SelectMany(x => x.Date, y => y.Prices});
```

And some other derivations but can't make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overload of `ToDictionary` with two `Func`s as arguments. The first `Func` will select your key, the second `Func` will select the value.

```
var dictionary = result.values.ToDictionary(x => x.Date, x => x.Prices);
```

See also the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__).

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I wanted :)